# Nargout, how to specify it when calling a function

Tags: matlab

In the definition of `nargout` the user can specify the number of outputs he wishes to see after calling the function, how does one specify  the number of outputs then?

I have considered the following example:

```
function [dif,absdif] = subtract(y,x)
dif = y - x;
if nargout > 1
   disp('Calculating absolute value')
   absdif = abs(dif);
end
```

When you call `subtract(2,4)` with any two numbers you will be presented with their difference. How do I return the absolute value of the difference then? I tried this:

`subtract(2,4,nargout=2)`, just out of the blue, unfortunately that didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nargout` does not allow one to "specify the number of outputs he wishes to see after calling the function". Rather, from the documentation for [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html):

> nargout returns the number of output arguments specified in the call to the currently executing function. Use this nargout syntax only in the body of a function.

In your example, `nargout` will return the number outputs requested when the function `subtract` is called. If the function is called as `subtract(y,x)`, `a=subtract(y,x)`, and `[a,b]=subtract(y,x)` the call to `nargout` will return `0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively. Thus, if you want the second output, you need to call `[a,b]=subtract(y,x)`.

I recommend that you read the documentation for [`function`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and the material on [creating and using functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html).